# In pdfbox, is there a way to find the content of a layer (ocg) or knowing if a particular content (text, rectangle, etc.) is linked to any layer?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I need to edit the content linked to a layer in a pdf document. For example, change the background color of a rectangle linked to a particular layer.

So far I retrieved the layers list but I'm being unable to know if there is any content linked to them.

(I'm using pdfbox-2.0.15)

Comment: There's a PDFMarkedContentExtractor class but I've never used it myself. If you know a bit about the content stream operators, then look at the content stream PDF with PDFDebugger.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you, I'm going to check that out.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr forgot to ask, do you think from your experience, that what I'm trying to do is possible with PDFBox?

Comment: Automatically => rather difficult. If it is a one time thing, then PDFDebugger would help finding what needs to be changed manually. PDF isn't made for editing.